# Hibernate Second level hit but still the database is hit as well for the same entity

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I'm using Hibernate 4.1.3 and am supprised to see that even while the second level cache is hit, the database is consulted as well for the same entity:

```
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache - com.behindmedia.btfd.model.UserCache: com.behindmedia.btfd.model.User store hit for com.behindmedia.btfd.model.User#2
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select user0_.id as id5_3_ .... etc
```

Looking at the stack trace it seems that the SQL is performed by the method that loads the entity from the second level cache:

loadFromSecondLevelCache in org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener (assembleCacheEntry).

Am I missing something here? I do use eager fetch annotations in the User class.

EDIT

I've got two entities, User and UserStats as follows:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private UserStats stats = new UserStats(this);
    ...
}

@Entity
public class UserStats extends AbstractUserStats {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "stats")
    private User user;
    ...
}
```

I found out that the problem is that even though the user is correctly retrieved from the 2nd level cache, the reverse mapping from UserStats to User is loaded from the database. This user is exactly the same as the one that was retrieved from the cache so it doesn't seem very logical to me.

Comment: Does the class you're retrieving have a collection? Could you paste the whole generated sql and the class too?

Comment: Maybe you should submit your hibernate annotated class or the hbm file if you are using that.